# ELAN TouchPad makes current window to lose focus when using two finger scroll

Tags: touchpad

I have an ASUS X52J laptop, running Windows 7 x64.

This problem appeared out of nowhere, and I don't even know where to start looking for a solution (Google wasn't of much help).

The pad itself works fine, when I stroke my finger over it the cursor responds well, tapping, two finger and three finger tapping all work.
The problem stars with the two finger scrolling.

On any window (I've tried Chrome, MSWord and PhpStorm), whenever I use two-finger scrolling, it will scroll for less than a second, then the window will lose focus (as if I clicked outside of it). This results in my having to click on the window, to resume scrolling, only for it to happen again once I try to scroll again.

What can cause it? A computer restart didn't help, no new software was installed since the last time I didn't have the problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to have sorted itself out. I'm not sure what the problem was or how it was fixed, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall ELAN touchpad drivers. Please mention on which software it is giving you this issue?
Adobe reader, internet explorer or anything?

Comment: Can you provide a Download-Link for the drivers?

Comment: It happens everywhere (I've tried Chrome, MSWord and PHPStorm). I'll try reinstalling and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install latest Elan tech Touch pad driver?

[Here](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Touchpad&os=30) is main Support page of Asus notebook Touch pad, Select Your OS then Select latest ELAN Driver Version. Remember to Remove Old Driver before installing new one.

Latest ELAN touch pad Driver is  V11.5.6.6  that can be downloaded for windows 7,8 x64 from [here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin8/Touchpad/Touchpad_Elantech_Win7_8_64_VER11566.zip).